# Clementine Play Count on Aquaris M10?

Tags: music, clementine, bq, aquaris, m10

Is it possible to track the play count or played status of music/podcasts managed with Clementine and played on the Bq M10? [asked by a new user of both]

*In response to Vistaus: "uClementine Remote" appears to be a program used on the M10 to remotely operate Clementine, as it plays on a nearby desktop. My intention is to play on the M10 when it far from the desktop and then sync with the desktop.*

Comment: I see. Thanks for elaborating your question. In that case, there's no such app yet on the M10.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is an app in the Ubuntu Store called *uClementine Remote*. That should do the trick.

Comment: Please elaborate your answer by explaining what exactly this app does and how to install it. Thank you.

Comment: Eh, how to install it? I already explained that: install it from the Ubuntu Store. The Ubuntu Store has a large launcher icon on the Apps screen, so that's hard to overlook... And what the app does should be straightforward from its title: it remote controls Clementine.